# WebStorm Marking Files as Invalid when using Require

Tags: webstorm

I' using the latest release version of webstorm (9.03) and most of my JavaScript files show up as invalid.  I'm showing the code below.

[image]

```
    'use strict';

    function SpeakerDetailsController (speaker, CONFIG, $sce, $scope) {
      this.speaker = speaker;
      this.showSessions = CONFIG.showSessions === 'True';

        $scope.someSafeContent = $sce.trustAsHtml("<i>Hello</i> <b>World!</b>");

    }
    SpeakerDetailsController.$inject = ['speaker', 'CONFIG', '$sce', '$scope'];

    export default SpeakerDetailsController;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure to set JavaScript Language Version to 'ECMAScript 6' (or 'JSX Harmony') in Settings/Languages&Frameworks/JavaScript to get ES6 syntax correctly recognized.